# Where to store files when Spring applicatoin is deployed on multiple servers

Tags: file, spring-boot, file-upload

I am developing an API that will be deployed to multiple servers. It is required that users are able to upload files. So far files are stored on the machine the server is running on. Obviously, this is not working when the application is deployed to multiple servers. So how could the files be managed in a scalable application? I am using Spring Boot to create my API, maybe it provides a more convenient solution.

Comment: Depending on your expected load a single database instance could be enough. Just save images in postgres/mariaDB/... that is running on a standalone server. In this case let all instances communicate with this single database. Or do you need a distributed database with multiple instances?

Comment: I need a distributed database with multiple instances

Comment: If you have finance you can opt for Cloud Storages like DropBox or Amazon Cloud Drive which have integration with spring boot, saving files into the database are expensive both in term of both storage or retrieval.

For DropBox - [link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java)
For Amazon  - [link](https://aws.amazon.com/products/storage/)

One option is for out of multiple server you can make one dedicated for file storage and make connection in the code towards this dedicated server for file storing and retrieval for files